# Can I skip a delimiter without repeating it in Kotlin/java.util.Scanner?

Tags: kotlin, java.util.scanner

Consider a string like

```
"1: 2, 3, 4"
^^  ^^^^^^^
id  items
```

I can parse this using

```
val sc = Scanner("1: 2, 3, 4")
val id = sc.useDelimiter(": ").nextInt()
val items = sc.skip(": ").useDelimiter(", ").asSequence().toList()
                    ^^^^
```

But I'd rather not repeat the first delimiter. Is there any solution without repeating it?

I would already be happy with a `skipCurrentDelimiter()` but didn't find anything like that.

Comment: Would storing the delimiter in a `final` variable satisfy your "no repeating the delimiter" requirement?

Comment: Yes, if there is no other way to move to the point where `next()` begins, that's one way to make it a bit nicer, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using [`delimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter()) to get the current delimiter pattern, and `skip` that?

```
sc.skip(sc.delimiter())
    .useDelimiter(", ").asSequence().toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

val INPUT_FORMAT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+): ((?:\\d+,? ?)+)")

fun main() {
    val input1 = "1: 2, 3, 4"
    val input2 = "2, 3, 4"
    try {
        println("Input 1 = \"${input1}\"")
        val result1 = parseString(input1)
        println("ID: ${result1.first}, Items: ${result1.second}")
        println("Input 2 = \"${input2}\"")
        val result2 = parseString(input2)
        println("ID: ${result2.first}, Items: ${result2.second}")
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        println(e.message)
    }
}

fun parseString(input: String): Pair<Int, List<Int>> {
    val matcher = INPUT_FORMAT_PATTERN.matcher(input)
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        val id = matcher.group(1).toInt()
        val items = matcher.group(2).split(", ").map { it.trim().toInt() }
        return Pair(id, items)
    } else {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid format")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Input 1 = "1: 2, 3, 4"
ID: 1, Items: [2, 3, 4]
Input 2 = "2, 3, 4"
Invalid format
```

Comment: Right, but this comes with a problem: Let's say someone forgot to prefix the ID in some line, leaving "2, 3, 4". I do want to catch this: the first delimiter must be a colon.

Comment: Understood, try a full regex.